# ./arrayScript.sh: 3: NAME[0]=Zara: not found

Tags: arrays, bash, shell

I am learning how shell scripting in Unix and have written a simple shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh

NAME[0]="Zara"
NAME[1]="Qadir"
NAME[2]="Mahnaz"
NAME[3]="Ayan"
NAME[4]="Daisy"
echo "First Index: ${NAME[0]}"
echo "Second Index: ${NAME[1]}"
```

However, whenever I run this in ubuntu as ./arrayScript.sh I am met with this error:

```
./arrayScript.sh: 3: NAME[0]=Zara: not found
./arrayScript.sh: 4: NAME[1]=Qadir: not found
./arrayScript.sh: 5: NAME[2]=Mahnaz: not found
./arrayScript.sh: 6: NAME[3]=Ayan: not found
./arrayScript.sh: 7: NAME[4]=Daisy: not found
./arrayScript.sh: 8: Bad substitution
```

I have come to understand that .sh files do not support arrays and that if I run the file as:

```
bash ./arrayScript.sh
```

It works fines, but I thought that running ./arrayScript.sh should have worked because that is what is given in the tutorial example? Can someone inform me whether I am doing something wrong, as I have copied the example letter for letter from here:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-using-arrays.htm

Comment: `sh` doesn't support arrays.

Comment: `sh` ([Bourne-shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourne_shell)) is **usally** not `bash` ([Bourne-again shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell))).

Comment: Fix your shebang.

Comment: Did OP forget he made this? Looks like a hit and run. :)

Answer (score 2):

`#!/bin/sh` is not bash. When you call it on cli with `bash ./arrayScript.sh`, the interpretor mentioned in the shebang is ignored and it will be parsed by bash. Your code works. When you simply call it with `./arrayScript.sh` it uses that shebang to determine the interpretor. You have `sh` and not `bash`, so it picks the wrong interpretor for the code in the file.

Replace `#!/bin/sh` with `#!/bin/bash` and you should be fine.